# Displaying images inside table using ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade

I am sending requests to an API using AJAX and retrieving a response with JSON containing image name and various data with it.

I am trying to display these images in a html table but for some reason only `404 - img not found` icons are displayed.

This is the code for generating the html from the AJAX response:

```
success : function(data){
    $('#t tbody#search').empty();
    if(data){
        $('#t tbody#all').hide();
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('#t tbody#search').append('' +
                '<tr><td> '+data[i].nom+' </td>' +
                '<td>'+data[i].prix+' </td>' +
                '<td>'+'<img src="{{asset('images/'~'+data[i].image +') }}"></td>'+
                '<td>'+data[i].quantite+' </td>'+
                '<td>'+data[i].descprod+' </td>  </tr>');
        };
    }
```

**Could someone explain what is going on?**

Comment: At first, you should check if the image exists.

Comment: it does exist but something wrong with the path in this line  '<td>'+'<img src="{{asset('images/'~'+data[i].image +') }}"></td>'+

Comment: Try replace `('images/'~'+data[i].image +')` With `(\'images/~'+data[i].image +'\')`

Comment: the same not found, the problem in the apostrophe ''

Comment: I don't know about `asset` part .. But what I know the `td` line should be `'<td><img src="{{asset(\'images/~'+data[i].image +'\') }}"></td>'+` .. So please copy/paste and replace your line with my line and try again

Comment: when i write src="images/'+data[i].image the path that take is /produit/images/a4b0ee1ff5f531edda05043231351231.jpeg where the image is under public/images even if i write  src="public/images/'+data[i].image it reads the wring path

Comment: So try the full path url something like `http://yourwebsite-or-localhost.com/public/images/'+data[i].image`

Comment: it search in produit/public/images that doesnt exist  but i want it to go to public/images it doesnt read the right path from the src=""

Comment: Its from `asset` part and I've no idea what is `asset` is .. So I'll upvote your question may someone else know

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Laravel Blade syntax:

```
{{ asset(...) }}
```

But that code is being excecuted by Javascript.  Laravel/Blade is not rendering this code, so that is not interpreted and converted into a URI here - it is just text to Javascript, and you'll just end up with that text in your `<img src>`.  Use [your browser's devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and inspect the generated table, you will see this.

You have a few choices to solve this:

1. If the back-end API where the data is coming from is your own application, just update it to include fully-qualified references to your images, so you don't need to do anything on the front end.  Eg on the back end add something like:

   ```
   // Pseudo-code, you have to adjust for whatever you have
   $data['fullimage] = asset('images/' . $image);
   ```

   Then in your Javascript you can just do:

   ```
   '<td><img src="' + data[i].fullimage + '"></td>' + ...
   ```
2. If you can't update the back end, you need to do what `asset()` normally does manually.  [Asset generates a URL](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-asset) based on the `ASSET_URL` you have in your `.env` file.

   - So say your `ASSET_URL` is `http://yourwebsite/images/`;
   - And an example `data[i].image` is `a4b0ee1ff5f531edda05043231351231.jpeg`
   - Then you can reference that in JS like this:

     ```
     '<td><img src="http://yourwebsite/images/' + data[i].image + '"></td>' + ...
     ```

   If this code is also running on `http://yourwebsite/`, then you don't even need that part, you can just use:

   ```
     '<td><img src="/images/' + data[i].image + '"></td>' + ...
   ```